# VUE : state variable undefined when accessing it in data() section through computed mapGetters()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've been using ...mapGetters a lot in my solution with success, but now that i need to access the variable directly in the data() section, it seems that the variable isn't set/ready when accessed..

the mapGetters are in the computed:{} section..

When debugging i notice that data() runs before computed:, so.. do i need to put a watch in some way here ?

**Code :**

```
data(){
        return {
            FiltersVisible: false,
            orderList: {
                currentPage: 1,
                totalPages: ordersCount / 20,
                // totalPages:80,
                itemsPerPage: 20
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['orders', 'ordersCount'])
        // ...mapGetters(['orders'])
    },
```

**Screenshot of Vue state (Chrome)**

Notice that the getters are initialized correctly....

[image]

Comment: Did you solve your problem? @Terje

Comment: yeah i did  :) It's quite a while ago so i don't remember exactly what the solution was though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle this. You can create a Vuex getter which supplies you a null value or default value to start with. This will at least ensure no errors and it will update whenever your store kicks into gear.

You could create a local computed property and fetch your store value with a `mapGetter` this way you can also supply a default.

You could have `totalPages` be set to 0 and use a watcher to update the value whenever your store value changes.

It really depends on context. For example a Vuex getter will be helpful if you need the same default fallback for other components who retrieve the value.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer @Stephan-v :).. Any chance you could show me (by code) the way you would have done this ? Aka.. the easiest :)